# Applescript: How to copy paste and click button from 2 applications?

Tags: applescript

I need to copy some data from Numbers and move them over to a GUI in Google Chrome browser. I need to click a button first to open up a textbox before pasting. Right now it will only copy the data from Numbers and will throw an error `System Events got an error: Can’t get application process "Google Chrome" of process "Google Chrome"`.

Here is my script:

```
    tell application "Numbers" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Numbers"
            keystroke "c" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 0.2

    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Google Chrome"
            click button "Add a New Value" of application process "Google Chrome"
            keystroke "v" using command down
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you are referencing `process "Google Chrome" of process "Google Chrome"` which occurs in the `click button` line.

---

```
tell process "Google Chrome"
   click button
```

is the same as

```
click button of process "Google Chrome"
```

so

```
tell process "Google Chrome"
    click button "Add a New Value" of application process "Google Chrome"
```

is the same as

```
click button "Add a New Value" of process "Google Chrome" of process "Google Chrome"
```

which causes the syntax error.

---

The solution is to change the line to

```
click button "Add a New Value"
```